# Precision loss in arithmetic short calculation

Tags: java, audio

I have to do a small program for school that converts a stereo file to mono (standard 16 bit wav) by calculating the mean between both stereo channels.

I have a reference mono file to check my result and I noticed some bytes are off by a single bit in my result file (top file is reference, bottom is my resulting file from the code):

[image: VBinDiff]

Here is the code from the method I use to make the "conversion":

```
    /**
 * 
 */
@Override
public void process() {

    int byteCount = 0;
    byte[] header = null;

    header = _input.pop(44);

    if (Convert.toInt(Arrays.copyOfRange(header, 22, 24)) == 2 && Convert.toInt(Arrays.copyOfRange(header, 34, 36)) == 16) {

        byteCount = Convert.toInt(Arrays.copyOfRange(header, 40, 44));

        _output.push(Arrays.copyOfRange(header, 0,4)); // ChunkID
        _output.push(Convert.toByte(byteCount/2 + 36)); // ChunkSize
        _output.push(Arrays.copyOfRange(header, 8, 22)); // Format & Subchunk1ID & Subchunk1Size & AudioFormat
        _output.push(Convert.toByte(1)); // NumChannels
        _output.push(Arrays.copyOfRange(header, 24, 28)); // SampleRate

        int SampleRate = Convert.toInt(Arrays.copyOfRange(header, 24, 28));
        int BitsPerSample = Convert.toInt(Arrays.copyOfRange(header, 34, 36));

        _output.push(Convert.toByte(SampleRate * 1 * BitsPerSample/8)); // ByteRate (SampleRate * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8)
        _output.push(Convert.toByte(1 * Convert.toInt(Arrays.copyOfRange(header, 34, 36))/8));// BlockAlign (NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8)
        _output.push(Arrays.copyOfRange(header, 34, 40)); // BitsPerSample & Subchunk2ID
        _output.push(Convert.toByte(byteCount/2)); // Subchunk2Size

        for (int i = 0; i < byteCount; i+=4) { // 4 bytes at a time

            short left = ByteBuffer.wrap(_input.pop(2)).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getShort();
            short right = ByteBuffer.wrap(_input.pop(2)).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getShort();

            short mean = (short) ((left + right) / 2); // Mono is the mean between both channels

            _output.push(ByteBuffer.allocate(2).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putShort(mean).array());

        }

        _input.close();
        _output.close();

    } else {

        System.out.println("Error! The file provided is not stereo or 16-bits! Aborting...");
        _input.close();
        _output.close();

    }

}
```

Where "_output.push()" and "_input.pop()" are simply utilities. They will return or write a byte array from/to the file. "Convert" is simply a class to convert from and to byte arrays.

Anyhow, I suspect the arithmetic calculation on the short is losing precision or something like that. Any idea where the problem is coming from and ideally how to fix it??

Comment: Two issues, integer division rounds down: (3 + 2) / 2 = 2. And then the signed numbers. (FF+00) / 2 = 8F or signed FF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was already mentioned in a comment but I'll elaborate on it a bit.

You are doing an integer division by 2 which will cause the result to be always truncated down. For example, `(2+1)/2 == 3/2 == 1` in plain integer arithmetic. This explains every case where your result is one less than the reference file. The way you would fix it is to use floating point for the intermediate computation:

```
short mean = (short)(Math.round((left + right) / 2.0f));
```

I'm not sure what is going on in the cases where your value is one greater than the reference file. If you post some sample values for left and right for one or more of those cases I can update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That seems to explain it but after checking with the professor, the original file was converted using a different method so the difference is normal. I have no need to worry about it. :)